# Plot linegraph of dataset with variable number of column

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

Depending on the input of my code - a varying number of columns are populated. I am attempting to create a loop which will only populate the columns which are populated. However, i am struggling as the loop keep overwriting and only retains the last line plotted on the graph. I though printing the ggplot would help - but sadly not!

```
plot <-   ggplot(plottable, aes(x = Date))
  ####for (i in 2:ncol(plottable)) {
  for (i in 2:ncol(plottable)) {
  Exposure <- assign(colnames(plottable)[i],plottable[,i])
  plot <- plot +
            geom_line(aes(y=Exposure, color = colnames(plottable)[i]))
    print(plot)
  }

plot
```

### Data

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18078, 18079, 18080, 18081, 18082), class = "Date"), Zone9 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Zone6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Zone4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Zone3 = c(0, 969698.444, 969698.444, 969698.444, 969698.444), Zone2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Zone11 = c(0, 15560719.2483794, 15560719.2483794, 15560719.2483794, 15560719.2483794), Zone10 = c(0, 2208064.625714, 2208064.625714, 2208064.625714, 2208064.625714), Zone1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you give a sample by using `dput` please?

Comment: structure(list(Date = structure(c(18078, 18079, 18080, 18081, 
18082), class = "Date"), Zone9 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Zone6 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Zone4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Zone3 = c(0, 969698.444, 
969698.444, 969698.444, 969698.444), Zone2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Zone11 = c(0, 15560719.2483794, 15560719.2483794, 15560719.2483794, 
    15560719.2483794), Zone10 = c(0, 2208064.625714, 2208064.625714, 
    2208064.625714, 2208064.625714), Zone1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks like something I would have tried before I got comfortable with `tidyr` and `ggplot`. I suggest a different approach that makes better use of these tools:

```
plottable %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = value, col = name)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy this is perfect. I definitely do need to get more comfortable with dplyr.

Comment: Great. To customize this, look at using `values_to` and `names_to` in the `pivot_longer` -- these will be the labels of the y-axis and color legend, respectively.

Comment: Also, if my answer solves your problem, consider designating it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would follow the approach using `tidyr::pivot_longer` as outlined by @AndyEggers. Nonetheless if you don't want to reshape your dataset you could add multiple `geom` layers to a plot using e.g. `lapply` or `purrr::map` like so:

```r
ggplot(plottable, aes(x = Date)) +
  lapply(names(plottable)[!names(plottable) %in% "Date"], function(x) {
    geom_line(aes(y=.data[[x]], color = x))  
  })
```

Making use of `ggplot2::economics` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(economics, aes(x = date)) +
  lapply(names(economics)[!names(economics) %in% "date"], function(x) {
    geom_line(aes(y=.data[[x]], color = x))  
  })
```

[image]